# how to make curve toolbar and tablayout?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-toolbar, android-xml, android-vectordrawable

I am trying to make thing like this but i couldn't do it any one can help me with this !
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [ArcLayout](https://github.com/florent37/ArcLayout) library.

1. Add dependency to build.gradle(app level)

   **compile 'com.github.florent37:arclayout:1.0.3'**
2. Add ArcLayout to your xml it can make curve inside or outside, inside in your case, so use this `app:arc_cropDirection="cropInside"` property.

   ```
   <com.github.florent37.arclayout.ArcLayout
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="200dp"
          app:arc_cropDirection="cropInside"
          app:arc_height="90dp"
          app:arc_padding="30dp"
          android:elevation="5dp"
          >

         <!--Your layout will be here to make toolbar -->
   ```